# Java: Replace / with \\/

Tags: java, rest, url

I have a URL containing an object that has a forward slash in its name: "/". The result is that it's ruining the URL construct. For example, for a URL with an object called David/, it looks like this: `http://..../David//questions`
I tried to write:

`objectName.replace(("/", "\\/")`

but it doesn't seem to be working.
What do I need to do in order to change the / to \/?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why is there a slash in the name in the first place? Just remove it. Escaping won't work anyway.

Comment: I know the best solution is removing the slash but unfortunately I can't do it.

Comment: Instead of *escaping* `/` you should probably *encode* it (as `%2F`)?

Comment: Hi, I tried encoding it with %2F. I'm using the URL in a REST request, and when I tried this solution I received "Object doesn't exist" response.

Comment: Changing `/` to `\/` should not help. The HTTP protocol should still interpret `/` as a delimiter no matter that there’s a \ in front of it. So after that substitution your path has three names in it, David\, \ and `questions`.I don’t know what your particular HTTP server expects, obviously, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s = "http://..../David//questions";
s = s.replaceAll("/", "\\\\/");
System.out.println(s);
```

Outputs:

```
http:\/\/....\/David\/\/questions
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Tomino, I used the 4 slashes solution and it worked!